# Background color does not change after assigning color code in getRowClass at viewConfig property

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Here, is **JavaScript** in which I am setting background color on those field which contain different data in **BusinessObject** column and **CustomTable** column.

```
projectgrid= new Ext.grid.GridPanel
     ({
         id:projectgrid,
         cm : projectInfoFieldsCM,
         store: inlineGridStore,
         stripeRows: true,
         autoScroll:true,
         width:550,
         height:500,
         bodyCssClass : 'customInlineGridCSS',
         viewConfig: 
         {
            forceFit: false,
            autoFill : false,
            deferEmptyText : false,
            emptyText : '<div align="center"><span style="font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal">No record available</span></span></div>',
            getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, store) {
                if(record.get('BusinessObject')!=record.get('CustomTable')){
                     return 'gender-male';
                }
            }
         }
      });
```

Here, Is **css** file in which I have assign color coding.
**Note :** I tried both ID which are declared in css file.

```
             .data-row-light-red
            {
            background-color: #ff0000 !important ;
            }

            .gender-male .ID {
                background-color: #088da5;
            }
```

Am I doing something wrong because I have implemented this functionality before but I am stuck in this one?

Comment: `.gender-male .ID` what is `.ID` here? I tried this code with just `.gender-male` and all works, whole grid row background color changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not want you exactly need but I already done something similar with renderer function in the column, maybe you going to be able to use that too?

Here is my code:

```
 columns: [
   {header: "Color", dataIndex: "COLOR", width:100,
     renderer: 
       function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
         metaData.style = "background-color: rgb(255,255,255);";
         return "";
       }                                        
  },
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to separate class selectors using comma

Try this

```
.gender-male, .ID
{
   background-color: #088da5;
}
```

Or

```
.gender-male
{
   background-color: #088da5;
}
```

If you don't need ID class anywhere

Comment: There is CSS problem in above query. When you are grouping the selectors then you need to separate each selector with a comma. That's why I suggested using comma between  '.gender-male' and '.Id'. This is how you can make '.gender-male' class accessible from ExtJs viewConfig object.